# When exporting object animation to FBX, final object is distorted and breaking mesh

Tags: modeling, animation, .fbx

I have created a blender animation project that consists of a 3d model with armature and a mesh cloak over the model. The model and the cloak have been parented with weights to the armature. When I preview the animation, it looks perfect (https://youtu.be/tQM2WS0a7eU) but after exporting into an FBX format, there is obvious displacement of cloak, distortion of model’s hands and shoulders and artifacting with the cloak during movement (https://youtu.be/XpxCQ2sIGFQ).

I have been beating my head against the wall for days trying to figure this out so any help would be very much appreciated.